# JQuery dynamic menu using nest JSON object first 2 level accordion, 3 and 4 hover popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have implemented jQuery dynamic menu using JSON nested Object.

1. Click on `Level 0` COLLAPSE `level 1` POPOVER
2. Click on `Level 2` POPOVER-HEADER `level 3` MODEL

Created dynamic nested `ul li` list using `jQuery each`. Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasanth1982/x62ad54e/)
But unable to handle above 4 levels any solution? appreciated Thanks.
[image: See] screenshot for more information

Comment: So whats the question? We dont write software for you, you write and we help.

Comment: Need help to display as showing in the screen shot now its looks like https://jsfiddle.net/vasanth1982/x62ad54e/ @Grumpy

Comment: i have implemented up to 2 level but remaining bit difficult to me please help ?